# Is it possible to use SourceLink feature "EmbedAllSources" in a C++ build?

Tags: c++, sourcelink

SourceLink supports feature "EmbedAllSources". It is well documented how to use this feature from a dotnet build. Is it possible to use the feature for a C++ build? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Unlike C#, C++ supports lots of compile time processing (e.g. templates don't exist at runtime). It is unclear what "embed all sources" means in the C++ context. If you want to expose some functionality, then I suppose `extern` is the standard way to do that. Otherwise what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @freakish I wanted to make my source code available when debugging on a remote system. If I was using GIT, SourceLink supports this natively, but I'm not using GIT, I'm using subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GitHub:

> The only feature currently supported is mapping of source files to the
>   source repository that is used by the debugger to find source files
>   when stepping into the code. Source embedding and embedding commit SHA
>   and repository URL information in the native binary are not supported
>   for native projects.

"Native" means C and C++, so no.

Comment: Thank you, on [re-reading](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#using-source-link-in-c-projects) this part of the documentation several times, I agree with your answer, I appreciate it.